# Result of recursive method

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I am trying to understand this recursive method but even with a debugger I couldn't come up to something that makes sense to me so i hope someone here is motivated to explain me what is going on here. I know how recursion works basically but the way this method is written down troubles me.
I know the conditional operator in java and I worked out a new code but still I don't understand it, so what I expect here is.

What is the result for m(5) AND m(15). How did you calculate it? Thanks

**Edit after the answers. I made a table with my results for future readers**

```
m(n)::|0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|...
result|0|0|1|1|1|2|3|4|6|9|13|19|28|41|60|88|...
```

I checked only the result of 15 with my program.

```
public class practice {

    /**
     * Try to understand the way this works
     * @param n
     * @return 
     */
    static long m(long n) {
        return n <= 1 ? 0 : n == 2 ? 1 : m(n - 1) + m(n - 3);
    }

    /**
     * This is what i tried so far.
     * @param n
     * @return 
     */
    static long ma(long n) {

        System.out.println("Method called");
        System.out.println("N is: " + n);
        if (n <= 1) {
            System.out.println("N<=1: " + n);
            System.out.println("0 is returned");
            return 0;
        } else if (n == 2) {
            System.out.println("N==2: " + n);
            System.out.println("1 is returned");
            return 1;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Inside ELSE, N is: " + n);
            return ma(n - 1) + ma(n - 3);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ma(15);
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you understand by recursion ?

Comment: Hello i thought my code explains the problem quite well and if it didn´t i added some text but to answer your question. Personally i think that recursion is a way in java to implement "for-loops" but in another way. You call yourself again and again until you reach a base case. This happens similar but unlike a forloop (where the "magic" happens automaticly) by calling your method inside the method. If you look at the code of my prof the first lines of code shows this. m(n - 1) + m(n - 3) << recursion. but i got stuck with the (recursion + recursion). Hope this answers your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrote it this way to make it more understandable:

```
m(0) = 0
m(1) = 0
m(2) = 1
m(n) = m(n - 1) + m(n - 3) // n >= 3
```

When we know the values for `m(0)`, `m(1)` and `m(2)`, we can calculate any `m(n)`, where `n >= 3`, using `m(n - 1) + m(n - 3)`. For any negative input, the result is 0.

For example:

```
m(3) = m(3 - 1) + m(3 - 3) = m(2) + m(0) = 1 + 0 = 1
m(4) = m(4 - 1) + m(4 - 3) = m(3) + m(1) = 1 + 0 = 1
m(5) = m(5 - 1) + m(5 - 3) = m(4) + m(2) = 1 + 1 = 2
```

And so on...

Comment: This made me finally understand it. Thanks for your help and thanks for all the other people. After reading this every answer makes sense now. I reached to calcualte it for m(15). Guess im prepared for the exam now for this cind of questions.

Answer (score 3):

Pencil and paper are you friends.

There are 3 cases  (two of them are base conditions)

```
if n <= 1  then return 0

if n == 2 then return 1

else recursive call to  m(n-1) + m(n-3)
```

So you know that on every recursive call we are approaching one of the base conditions.

Here is a stack trace of what happens on `m(5)`

```
                                m(5)
                    m(4)         +          m(2)
        m(3)         +      m(1)            return 1
m(2)     +      m(0)        return 0
return 1        return 0
```

Adding all the returns gives   `1 + 0 + 0 + 1` which is `2`

So

```
m(5) == 2
```

Comment: Your answer starts explaining really well but i lost myself and i still do in the stack trace. Altough i know what you are trying to explain and that the effort to print this stack trace here was high, for me personally it is confusing. Combining the first part of your answer with the answer of Bubletah is in my opinion a perfect answer to this question. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Method `m` in pseudo code. (this is some kind of scala/python mash up)

```
def m (number n)
    if (n <= 1)       0
    else if (n == 2)  1
    else              m(n - 1) + m(n - 3)
```

Looking at this you can see that anything `<= 2` is a terminal operation, returning `0` or `1` based on the input. If `n` is > 2, the fun begins. Take for example `n=3`. Since `3` is greater than `2`, we need to run the third `if`. When we look at that line we see that we nee to return `m(n - 1) + m(n - 3)`. Plugging `n = 3` in, it looks like this: `m(3 - 1) + m(3 - 3)`, or, more simplified, like this: `m(2) + m(0)`. This will now terminate with `1` because neither `2` or `0` for `n` will result in more calling of `m`.

So now we have something we understand we can now workout what `m(15)` and `m(5)` will return.

I will only work it out for `5` since the call stack for `15` would be way to long

```
                   m(5)
              /           \
           m(5-1)   +    m(5-3)
        /         \         |
      m(4-1)  +  m(4-3)     |
    /       \       |       |
  m(3-1) + m(3-3)   |       |
    |        |      |       |
    1    +   0   +  0   +   1
                 2
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hello you start really good but i lose my self in the stack trace. Thanks for your reply but to answer such a question with a stack trace, in my opinion its a little bit confuseable. Anyway thank you very much for your efford.

Comment: Yeah it looks way better now ! I gave you my one and only vote and voted this up =)

Comment: it seems so easy that i feel stupid having asked this question haha but i am sure i wasn´t able to solve this on my own before.

Answer (score 2):

```
m(5) = m(4)+m(2) // 5>2, so the third condition
m(4) + m(2) = m(3)+m(1) + 1 // 4>2, so the third condition
m(3) + m(1) + 1 = m(2)+m(0) + 0 + 1 // 3>2, so the third condition
m(2) + m(0) + 0 + 1 = 1 + 0 + 0 + 1 = 2
```

Now, between transformations, `m(2)` s instantly replaced with `1`, and `m(n<=1)` is instantly replaced with `0`. This is how you can analyze this on paper. Computer, however, would wirst calculate `m(4)` before calculating `m(2)` and adding the results in the first line - this happens because of order of poerations within the recursive functions.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply i try to analyze this on paper. I start to follow your comment and will reply as soon as i run into trouble. Thanks

Comment: Ok i understood it for m(5), now i get this. I will try it for m(15) and respond. Thanks very much.

Comment: Thanks for your answer it made me understand the concept but i still had it wrong. To improve your answer by the knowledge i have now. 
m(0) = 0;
m(1) = 0;
m(2) = 1;
m(3) = m(n-1) + m(n-3) = m(2) + m(0) = 1 + 0 = <1>;
m(4) = m(3) + m(1) = 1 + 0 = <1>;
m(5) = m(4) + m(2) = 1 + 1 = 2.

Thanks for your help but the answer who finally made me understand this was another. Anyway thank you very much.